# cron on resque scheduler not working on preferred intervals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, resque

I need to run a task precisely on 10AM every thursday,

on resque yaml file I am trying this

```
cron: "* 10 * * 4 * America/New_York"  # expecting this to shoot out every thursday..
```

Was that correct? I can't test it out as I can't wait for such an interval, so I tried to test it at least for every 5 mins but it isn't very promising

```
cron: "5 * * * * *"  # It runs for every single minute..
```

any help or direction is appreciated.

I followed this

```
* * * * * *
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

Comment: The docs for this particular implementation allow 6 fields, but when 6 are used, the first field represents seconds not minutes. See https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex expressions can have 5 or 6 placeholders. Not every framework/implementation supports both ways so you have to check which format you need.

Your expression `cron: "5 * * * * *"` would run every minute exactly 5 seconds past the minute.
I think in your case, you could use only 5 placeholders which means that you can not schedule for seconds but only for minutes.

Also, to run something every 5 minutes, you need the following expression:

```
cron: "*/5 * * * *"
```

Every 10AM on thursday should be:

```
cron: "0 10 * * 4 America/New_York"
```

Meaning:

- every thursday (4)
- every month
- every day
- 10 hours
- 0 minutes

(I have not tested this.)

Comment: There's a 6 placeholders syntax, where the first one is for the seconds, cf the end of [this section](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler#scheduled-jobs-recurring-jobs)

Comment: @zmo, you are right, I have updated my answer. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

There are normally only 5 fields for cron. The implementation of cron you are using allows 6 fields but the first field stands for seconds not minutes. From https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler:

> NOTE: Six parameter cron's are also supported (as they supported by rufus-scheduler which powers the resque-scheduler process). This allows you to schedule jobs per second (ie: "30 * * * * *" would fire a job every 30 seconds past the minute).

So you should drop to the normal 5 fields and use the @thomas-d's answer.

Traditional 5 field format is:

```
Minute Hour Day_of_the_Month Month_of_the_Year Day_of_the_Week
```